# Joomla: pages not found after copying site to another directory

Tags: joomla, http-status-code-404, joomla1.5

I have copied a live joomla site. The original is found at [this][1] website. The copied one in found [here][2]. But all links (e.g. in the left navigation menu) result in 404 errors. The administrator backend is accessible and i can create new menu items in the copied one but they all result in 404 errors.

I did adjust the     configuration.php file so    var $tmp_path    var $log_path point the right paths. i updated     var $live_site = 'http://hosting01.hestronic.nl/~ijskoud2

The live_site was empty in the original configuration.php file.

Do i still need to run an update or something?

Thank you

PS joomla 1.5.25

Answer (score 2):

Turn off search engine friendly url feature in System -> global configurations.
If you really want to enable SEF URL then you need to set your rewrite base according to your site dir in the server.

For $live_site variable, no need to modify it and keep it empty.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue where all of my links were doubling up. Fixed by prefixing `http://` to `$live_site`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to $live_site, just leave it blank. The tmp and log paths are the only thing you need to touch. If you have SEF URLs turned on, you will also need to change the rewrite base from `/` to what ever the subdirectory is.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with my friend @Brent. 
Go to your DB to the menu table (by default its called jos_menu) and look for the "path" column. you probably need to manually fix the paths of all your menus to point to the new folder.

Comment: thanks for the info, but i only see a column "link" which is filled with values like     index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63  i wouldnt know what to change in these fields.

Comment: There's supposed to be both "link" and "path" columns: http://docs.joomla.org/Tables/menu

Comment: i switched off SEF urls for now and everything works. For testing this is sufficient, thanks antway

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `.htaccess` file exists in your new folder. if not exists remove the `sef url configuration` from admin side.